# ads showing in old release build of an app but not in recent one

Tags: flutter, admob

recently I've build a release of an app and found no ads are showing neither banner or native ads, but I have another old version of the same app and the ads are working in it!
the same ad units and the same app id;
all i get is this:

```
W/flutter ( 2825): onAdFailedToLoad: 3
I/Ads     ( 2825): Ad failed to load : 3
```

anyone has an explanation for this?

Comment: check this out:https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem cause was the Keystore used in the app;
real ads didn't show when using a recently created Keystore (this was the stuck);
also didn't show if I don't provide Sha1 of the keystore to firebase (i use firebase);
also didn't show if I use adblocker app in the client phone;